# Proper punctuation in abbreviation of Nota Bene

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

Which of the following are "correct" ways to abbreviate Nota Bene?

- N.B. blahblah
- n.b. blahblah
- NB. blahblah
- nb. blahblah
- NB: blahblah
- nb: blahblah
- NB blahblah
- nb blahblah
- (etc.)

Authoritative sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: In Italy you will see it as N.B. and usually it's the most common spelling also abroad. I've seen NB: but honestly, it doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Alenanno I personally tend toward NB: but I don't know of any legitimate style guides that condone this usage, which is what led me to ask the question.

Comment: The difference would be in what country or what language you'd write in, I guess.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote; Internet reference sources generally disagree here. Wikipedia says "often abbreviated as N.B.", thefreedictionary.com says "Abbr. NB", wiktionary says "abbreviated form n.b.", CMOS gives "NB, n.b." - none give special emphasis nor assert exclusivity in their correctness.

Comment: If there isn't a correct answer, then it means you are fairly free to choose your preferred acronym/abbreviation.

Comment: @DanBurton, You're missing one which I use: "Nb". ["N" is caps because it's the start of the sentence.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch10/ch10_sec043.html) says:

> **NB**, **n.b.** *nota bene*, take careful note (capitals are illogical but often used for emphasis)

CMS adds that "Latin abbreviations are often set in roman" (i.e. not italic).

I tend to see

> NB: The Smiley Police are lurking.
>
> "...whom, n.b., I had never seen."

Comment: I notice that it's often **NB** - I think you (and CMOS) are right that the rational is "emphasis". We don't normally expect to see **EG**, for example, but with "n.b." there often *is* an implied stress that would be articulated if you were reading out loud from the text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "n.b." itself is an emphasis. For more emphasis, use: "**n.b.**" or "n.b.!".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, You could also emphasize the note itself like this: "N.B.: **Version 2.0 changed everything.**"

Answer (score -1):

This should suffice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

Comment: Not exactly authoritative references there.

Comment: Right you are, Dan. But from what I've witnessed here for the past three days, questions whose answers can be readily and satisfactorily apprehended online are soon closed by moderators on that basis. Perhaps preventing of this would follow from explaining why it is that the accepted, common abbreviation proves, in your case, unsatisfactory.

Comment: ...or rather closed on that basis by users with rank sufficient to make that call.

Comment: Giving a link to Wikipedia isn't the same as giving an answer.  The definition in Wikipedia also doesn't answer the original question about punctuation.

Comment: I would have to agree that the usefulness of the Wikipedia link is a function of one's more generalized problem solving ability, which is to say one's ability to integrate its information with other freely availbale, related material. A couple things come to mind.

Comment: Well, a few. One is that Latin abbreviations, by Cassell's, follow always the non-italicized, upper case model followed by periods after each letter, the only exception being [some] single-word abbreviations like "Non." for "nonae." Periods regardless.  (See qualifying note below.)

Comment: The second [thing that comes to mind] is that the reader is expected to be able to infer, in context, what [it is that] an abbreviation stands for. The writer's responsibility is to set things up in such a way as to make that happen (make it easy), though certainly even spelling out the abbreviation would be lost on some readership. (One targets the able, not the LCD.)  For example, before using "Ti." for Tiberius the first time, one would want to spell out the name in a prior place.

Comment: This point is readily discernible because, as predictable, the same abbreviation is at times used to mean entirely different things. Cassell's uses "D.M." for "dis manibus." The Wikipedia link uses it for dignum memoria. It is the writer’s unique burden to make that determination and well implement it. Without specifics, which the question does not provide, it is impossible to make recommendations which are tailored to one’s effort.

Comment: Thirdly, as mentioned in passing, there’s rarely a pressing burden to abbreviate Latin terms. Exceptions are the grossly familiar. One might write scilicet instead of “s.c.,” but never et cetera for “e.g.” We know this simply by convention, just as we know that lower case letters are freely used, even for b.c. and a.d. Why not? So while it becomes obvious either N.B. or n.b. would do for nota bene, again presuming of one’s reader a certain facility or breadth of knowledge, one would not in any event omit periods.

Comment: Context. One or more periods. And the freedom to spell out a great many and especially obscure words or terms. These are EVIDENT core principles which go to the original question. A final is that some terms are so obscure as to make abbreviating them a fool’s errand.

Comment: edit -- but never et cetera for “etc.”